# Backbone: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am getting some data and creating a collection with it like this:

```
reader: function(fileName){
        console.log(fileName);
        _this = this;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "some/rest/url",
            data: {"fileName": fileName},
            success: function(response) {
                console.log("reader");
                console.log(response);
                importCollection = new ImportCollection(response);
                importCollection.sync();
            }
        });
    },
```

My collection looks like this:

```
define([
        "underscore",
        "backbone",
        "models/import",
    "helpers/localstorage"
   ],
function(_, Backbone, ImportModel, localstorage) {

return Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: ImportModel,
    url: "some/rest/url",

    projectId: null,

    fetch: function(options){
        //TODO remove this hardcode
        console.log(options.url);
        this.url = this.url + "/PU000101/reader";

        Backbone.Collection.prototype.fetch.call(this,options);
    }

});

});
```

And my model looks like this:

```
define([
"models/base"
```

],
function(BaseModel) {

```
return BaseModel.extend({

    idAttribute: "id",
    url: "some/rest/url",


});

});
```

Ideally what i want to happen on sync is that the collection would post all of its models to the backend for validation but i keep getting this error: `A "url" property or function must be specified`

Answer (score 0):

If you call `sync()` directly, you'll need to pass in the arguments that it expects. Right now, you aren't passing anything to your `importCollection.sync()` call, so when Backbone tries to resolve what url to use here

```
if (!options.url) {
  params.url = _.result(model, 'url') || urlError();
}
```

it won't find a url and will execute `urlError()`. You need to either call your overloaded `fetch()` method, or pass the correct parameters in your `sync()` call. Notice that `fetch()` for Backbone.Collection calls `sync` this way:

```
return this.sync('read', this, options);
```